# PHP fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu

Tags: magento2, topmenu, magento2.2.6, megamenu

this is happening when I install megamenu from template monster and updated to **Magento 2.2.6** any ideas? full error below

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\StateDependentCollectionFactory, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory given, called in /home/olabrava/public_html/app/code/TemplateMonster/Megamenu/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php on line 27 and defined in /home/olabrava/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php:47 Stack trace: #0 /home/olabrava/public_html/app/code/TemplateMonster/Megamenu/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php(27): Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory), Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver)) #1 /home/olabrava/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): TemplateMonster\Megamenu\Plugin\Block\Topmenu->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalo in /home/olabrava/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php on line 47

Comment: did you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command ?

Comment: run command `rm -rf generated/*` first and then run setup command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: did both and still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Plugin/Block/Topmenu.php`

The constructor of this class looks like

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\StateDependentCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
    )
```

Now, open `TemplateMonster\Megamenu\Plugin\Block\Topmenu` and take a look at its `__construct` method.

Your first check should be if `parent::_construct()` is called.

If it does, what parameters are send there?

Your checks here:

A. Does `parent::__construct` receives 4 parameters?

B. What variable is send as a second parameter?

This last one is actually the problem: the second parameter that you send is NOT of type

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\StateDependentCollectionFactory
```

but of type

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
```

Inject the correct type for the second parameter, confirm that the rest are send as expected, re-compile if you must, and you are done :).

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome.